# Angular + Firebase: how to store/retrieve objects with list properties?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

chatroom.service.ts:

```
...
export class Message {
  author: string;
  body: string;
}

export class Chatroom {
  title: string;
  messages: Message[];  // <-- seems to be the problem
}

@Injectable()
export class ChatroomService {
  ...
  getChatroom = (chatroomId: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<Chatroom> =>
    this.db.object('/chatrooms/' + chatroomId);
  ...
```

chatroom.component.ts:

```
...
export class ChatroomComponent implements OnInit {
  chatroom: Chatroom;

  private sub: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.sub = this.chatroomService.getChatroom(params['chatroomId'])
          .subscribe(chatroom => this.chatroom = chatroom);
      });
  }
  ...
```

chatroom.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="chatroom">
  <p *ngFor="let message of chatroom.messages">{{message.author}}: {{message.body}}</p>
</div>
```

error:

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

The problem is that the Chatroom object's "message" property is treated by Firebase as an object and whereas I want it to be treated an ngFor-iterable list. Any suggestions on how to make this work?

EDIT: Here is the Firebase data structure:

```
{
  "chatrooms" : {
    "chatroom_342768235" : {
      "title" : "a chatroom",
      "messages" : {
        "message_3252253" : {
          "author" : "Joe",
          "body" : "test message"
        },
        "message_2653837" : {
          "author" : "Kim",
          "body" : "another message"
        }
      }
    },
    "chatroom_426482763" : {
      "title" : "another chatroom",
      "messages" : {
        "message_1243525" : {
          "author" : "Tom",
          "body" : "blah blah"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: show what is inside chatroom?

Comment: do you use angularfire2 (https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)?

Answer (score 0):

I think because you listen to the DB ( with subscribe) you get an Observable list, and *ngFor cant work with that kind of lists. You should try to add pipe of |async after the Observable list you want to iterate. Something like this:

```
<p *ngFor="let message of chatroom.messages | async">{{message.author}}: {{message.body}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible add a setter/getter methods to`messages` property in `Chatroom` class.

Declare `messages` property as `typed array`.

```
export class Chatroom {
  title: string;
  private _messages : {[key: string]: Message[]}; 

  public set messages(value: {[key: string]: Message[]}) {
        this._messages = {};
        for (let msg in value) {
               this._messages[msg] = value[msg];
        }
  }

  public get messages(): {[key: string]: Message[]} {
    return this._messages;
  }

}
```

With this approach `messages` property is a proper array with string index and should be iterable now. Only reason for using typed array is you can access the name of messages `message_2653837` and `message_3252253`.